# cc.net dynamic parameters in publisher block

Tags: cruisecontrol.net

I am Using CC.Net to run an .exe file after project build is complete and need to pass the project name, publish date/time and user on the command line as parameters to the .exe. However I can't get cc.net to recognise these a dynamic properties and replace them with the correct values.

```
<publishers><exec executable="C:\MyApp.exe"></exec><buildArgs>"$[$CCNetProject]" "$[$CCNetBuildDate]" "$[$CCNetBuildTime]" "$[$CCNetUser]"</buildArgs><buildTimeoutSeconds>30</buildTimeoutSeconds></publishers>
```

Answer (score 1):

The correct syntax for properties in ccnet config is $[CCNetProject]

Answer (score -1):

I believe the correct syntax for properties in ccnet config is:

```
$[CCNetProject]
```

Rather than:

```
$[$CCNetProject]
```